# How to set the list divider of an MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to find the way to set the list divider of a MultiAutoCompleteTextView, but it does not seem to have an android:divider property nor a setDivider() method. Is it possible at all to change the default divider resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have read that it requires creating styles and applying them to the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`

[Styling an AutoCompleteTextView](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2012/11/styling-autocompletetextview.html)

But I have not figured out how to make this work.