# MultiAutoCompleteTextView suggestion separator color

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, multiautocompletetextview

I'm using `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` in my Android app. I need to customize the suggestion list of this control. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383176/how-to-set-the-list-divider-of-an-multiautocompletetextview) to customize the list separator color but this didn't worked for me. How can I update the default list divider color of `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the `divider` color, you need to also set the `dividerHeight` property or it won't work. And the `Popup` used by the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` is actually a `ListView`, so setting that is correct here.

Add this to your styles.xml file:

```
<style name="myStyle" parent="@android:style/THeme.Holo.Light"> <!-- or whatever style you inherit -->
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListViewStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2px</item>
</style>
```

This will set the dividers in the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`'s `Popup` to orange.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the divider color of the ListView showing your results.  This is set with the `divider` attribute.

Like this: `android:divider="@color/mycolor`

As an alternative, you could also create a custom drawable using a ShapeDrawable, that contains it's own custom divider color, then you apply that drawable as the background to your list element.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. It's not about setting divider color of `ListView`. Insteadt it is about setting divider color of suggestion popup list of `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` control of Android API.