# How to change default color of underline in edit text to red?

Tags: android

I am using AppCompat light theme with dark action bar. I want to change the color of edit text underline to red. Please help how can i do it.

Comment: create a custom 9patch drawable and attach it in your edittext

Comment: Can i simply do it by xml code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/red"/>
```

Comment: Can it done to change the color of break line of drop down list?

Comment: No that's done differently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801498/multiautocompletetextview-suggestion-separator-color

Answer (score 2):

The color of the edit text underline is set to the colorAccent of your theme. If you do not want to change the colorAccent of your whole application, you can make a custom theme and apply it to the edit text view with `android:theme`.